# Download zip file from website with selection to R

Tags: r, download

I would like to download data from [this links](http://www.hactl.com/en-US/Media-Centre/Cargo-Statistics.aspx#.U0-GDvmSxCY)

[image]

The tasks would be:

1. download the winzip file
2. unzip the file
3. save it to specific location, lets say C:/data.

Although I have limited knowledge on html, I think the following html code is related to the form:

```
<tr class="downloadStatisticItem" Style="display: table-row;">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: recently i learnt to download online data using RCurl with a url link. While this situation is totally different. When i clicked submit. it do not give a url.

Comment: Why add a screenshot of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I downloaded this file and link looks like this
   http://www.hactl.com/webapp/hactlpbf/pbfcontroller/HDCRDF;PBF_JSESSIONID=Pvl9TPbB7585NLhLTy9vKQTh9Mj42GW2P10LTVGHKnSwznRwwKy5!-315031026
   so it might be hard to download this using R, since there is no static link. But you could try using `postForm` function from `RCurl` package like this

   `postForm("www.hactl.com/en-US/Media-Centre/Cargo-Statistics.aspx",dateTo='Mar 2014', (insert here the rest of form inputs), style="POST")`
2. To unzip file use `unzip` function
3. To copy file to specific location use `file.copy` function.

Comment: Thanks. @bartekartanus. as i spot <input type="radio" value="1" name="fileFormat" checked="checked"> if i want to select raw data excel then i need to select value=1. I should type fileFormat="1" ?